# From generators as linear space to minimal generators as ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I$ be a prime ideal in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

Suppose we find a family $\{p_n\}_n$ of generators of $I$ *as a linear space*.
Clearly $\{p_n\}_n$ generates $I$ also as an ideal.
Is it possible to extract from $\{p_n\}_n$ a family of generators of $I$ *as an ideal* having *minimal cardinality*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and consider the ideal $I=(x)$ in $k[x]$, which is of course prime and principal. The set $B=\{x+x^2\}\cup\{x^i:i\geq2\}$ is a basis of $I$ as a $k$-vector space  yet no element of $B$ generates $I$ as an ideal.

You can play similar games with three variables.

Comment: Thank you. My conjecture has benn easly destroyed :D